# I accidentally removed the core blocks from content region

Tags: blocks, theming

I accidentally remove the core/system blocks that normally sit under the content region and now I am not able to access any of the administration page.

If I visit my site/user/login, or register, etc, it shows me everything as per the markup I created

Is there a way I can re-add those blocks to the content region without being logged in?
Any database query, drush command or drupal console?

Comment: If your site is managed via configuration management you could do `drush cim`. Or navigate to https://example.com/admin/structure/block and put them back. I don't understand what this means: `it shows me everything as per the markup I created`.

Comment: Making sure you're running in a dev/test environment (you don't want to test anything on a prod site for obvious reasons), try `drush theme:uninstall seven; drush theme:enable seven`. Disabling and enabling themes sometimes (always?) has the effect of resetting the block layouts to default in my experience

Comment: @clive your suggestion worked. Using drush I managed to activate seven: drush theme:enable seven and finally drush config-set system.theme default seven.
Also I ended up noticing that the region showing the content was wrapped in an if statement which would never be truthful for pages that aren't a node. :(

Comment: Ouch. I'd be `git blame`ing that one straight away...